# Building navigation route from user specified directions not a final destination

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, mobile, gps

I am writing a mobile application that uses the GPS navigation functionality on the device but I would like to use it in an unconventional way. I do not want the user to input a final destination to begin the navigation. Instead I would like to allow the users to build the route the navigation will take them on by specifying each step. As an example I would like the user to be able to input parameters into the app like go straight on street x and then turn on street y and the app will build the navigation route according to those parameters but I have been unable to find how to do this or even if it is possible. I have only been able to find different ways to launch the navigation application from my own application and how to pass a final destination to it so that the user does not have to, which isn't what I want to do. Is there a way to build a navigation route in this way?

Comment: Were you answered somehow? If so, remember to accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that's a pretty difficult thing to do, but you should check what Google calls [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints).

The last *step* the user marks each time would be a **destination**, and all the steps inbetween would be **waypoints**.

Somebody posted an example on how to use waypoints in Android [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/). **However**, you should now translate this "turn left to X street" to a real address, based on your last waypoint (which in my opinion is the hardest part).

Good luck with that